# Quel temps utiliser dans une phrase au passé qui contient « depuis » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, conjonctions, discours-indirect

**Cas 1.** À la page 192 dans *Advanced French Grammar* de Véronique Mazet, il est écrit :

> When depuis = since in a negative sentence : If the context is past, the imparfait is used for the main verb (never the passé composé), and the verb in the depuis que clause is in the pluperfect.
>
> Example: Nous ne nous PARLIONS plus depuis qu'elle m'avait menti. = We were not talking to each other anymore ever since she had lied to me.

**Question 1.** Pourquoi pas la suite ?

> Nous ne nous SOMMES plus PARLÉ depuis qu'elle m'avait menti.

**Cas 2.** La transformation du discours direct au discours INdirect réclame la même transformation. (où le présent doit être modifié à l'imparfait, et non pas au passé composé).

> Par exemple : J’ai annoncé : « Ça y est » → J’ai annoncé que ça y était.

**Question 2.** Dans ces deux cas, pourquoi le présent, doit-il être modifié à l'imparfait, et non pas au passé composé ? Je pense que je comprends l'essentiel sur les différences entre le PC et l'imparfait.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien la question... quel verbe voudriez-vous mettre au passé composé ? Pourquoi tout le monde parle de ce livre ?

Comment: Tout le monde, tout le monde... Essentiellement l'OP ces dernières 24 heures :)

Comment: @mlwacosmos : Merci de votre commentaire. Je ne parle pas d'un verbe spécifique. Je ne me préoccupe que du cas général, où présent --> imparfait (et NON PAS le passé composé). Faites-le moi savoir s'il vous faut plus d'éclaircissements.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: LOL. Veuillez m'excuser si j'en ai trop parlé ou si j'ai posé trop de questions sur ce livre. Je tâche de maîtriser son contenu.

Comment: D'après ce que je comprends, la question est : Pourquoi utiliser "Nous ne nous parlions plus" au lieu de "Nous ne nous étions plus parlées". Est-ce correct, @LaPrevoyance ?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Voilà l'exemple qui motive ma question généralisée : Dans cet example susdit et quand on mets le voix actif au voix passif, pourquoi le présent devient-il l'imparfait (et non pas le PC)? Je modifierai mon post original pour se l'éclarcir.

Comment: Désolé à tous. Je voulais dire (le discours direct --> indirect) en écrivant (le voix actif --> passif). Voici peut-être la source de confusion que j'ai corrigée.

Comment: Est-ce que c'est juste moi ou qqun devrait faire références aux règles de concordance des temps?

Answer (score 4):

> Nous ne nous parlions plus depuis qu'elle m'avait menti.

Nous ne nous sommes pas parlé pendant l'intervalle de temps entre le moment où elle m'a menti et le moment considéré dans le passé.

> Nous ne nous sommes plus parlé depuis qu'elle m'a menti.

Nous ne nous sommes pas parlé pendant l'intervalle de temps entre le moment où elle m'a menti et maintenant (à noter aussi que le temps de mentir a aussi changé).

Comment: Euh pourquoi changer la structure ? L'équivalent présent c'est « Nous ne nous parlons plus depuis qu'elle m'a menti. ». Ta seconde phrase correspond à « Nous ne nous étions plus parlé, depuis qu'elle m'avait menti. ». (Je menace de retirer mon upvote si ce n'est pas corrigé :-p)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, mon objectif était de montrer l'effet de l'utilisation du passé composé pour _parler_ puisque la question est « pourquoi l'imparfait plutôt que le passé composé ».

Comment: @Unfrancophone: J'ai mis à jour mon post original. SVP, puis-je vous y attirer votre attention ?

Answer (score 1):

L'imparfait sert à relater des événements passés. En plus on utilise **depuis** ici,  ce qui signifie que l'on veut traduire une habitude passée : l'imparfait existe en autres pour cela, exprimer des habitudes passées. (habitudes avec un sens très large, disons une continuité)

http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-10882.php